# How to upload image dynamically using implode function in php?

Tags: php, html

[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhZI2.png) 
I am getting this error multiple times.This code what ever you send I tested it.
In DB, I taken the `property_id` is `Integer` type and `Property_img` is `varchar`

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['property_id'],$_FILES['files'])){  // check that needed superglobals are set
    $query="INSERT INTO img_tbl(`property_id`,`property_img`) VALUES(?,?)"; //'$property_id','$join_string')";
    if($stmt=$conn->prepare($query)){
        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$tmp_name){
            $property_img[]=$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $join_string=implode(' ',array_slice($_FILES['files']['name'][$key],0,5));
            copy($tmp_name,'uploads/'.$join_string);
        }
// I don't know the value type of $property_id.  If integer, use i instead of s.
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('is',$property_id,$join_string)){
            echo "bind failed";  // $stmt->error;  // do not echo when public
        }elseif(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo "execute failed";  // $stmt->error;  // do not echo when public
        }else{
            header('location:listpro_img.php');
        }
        $stmt->close(); 
    }else{
        echo "prepare failed"; // $mysqli->error;  // do not echo when public
    }
    $conn->close();
}else{
    echo "insufficient data submitted";
}
?>
```

-----------Here is HTML code for uploading n number of images at a time------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">  
  </head>
<script>
</script>
  <body id="top">



    <!-- begin:content -->
    <div id="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

                    <!-- Add form Code from Here -->

                          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          <div class="col-sm-12">

                             <div class="col-sm-6"><label>Property Id:</label></div>

                             <div class="col-sm-6 btn btn-info">    
                                   <input type="text" name="property_id"/></div>    
                              <div class="col-sm-6"><label>Property Image:</label></div>                              
                                  <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple /><br>      

                               <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <input type="submit" name="submit">
                             </div>
                          </div>                                   
                       </form>

                    <!--Form code Ends Here -->
                  </div>
                </div>           
            </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: User print_r or var_dump functions to debug the code and see what are the values in the $_POST that are being passed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with keeping your original code in the question.  This makes my answer meaningful.  My new code doesn't use `array_slice()` anymore.  Please show me the superglobal data that I have requested so that I can answer your question with confidence and I don't get "scooped" by another volunteer after spending my time helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I ran your html on one of my servers to see what kind of `$_POST` & `$_FILES` data I was dealing with.  I uploaded three small jpgs and got this:

```
$_POST=['property_id'=>'test','submit'=>'Submit'];
$_FILES=['files'=>[
            'name'=>['4x4.jpg','catfish.jpg','calc.jpg'],
            'type'=>['image/jpeg','image/jpeg','image/jpeg'],
            'tmp_name'=>['/tmp/phps6I8zU','/tmp/phpgbmn2z','/tmp/phpo9wSgg'],
            'error'=>[0,0,0],
            'size'=>[14243,43314,36173]
        ]
    ];
```

*Mind you, I needed to remove the `btn btn-info` classes so that I could actually access the text field.

---

From this I realized that you were calling `implode()` from inside your `foreach()` loop and that was fouling things up.  `$join_string` was getting called on each iteration (1 for each file uploaded).  Even if `implode()` was receiving an array (and it wasn't), you were overwriting `$join_string` each time.

This is my updated code -- loaded with error checking to help you to isolate and mop up any left over issues:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['property_id'],$_FILES['files'])){  // check that needed superglobals are set
    $query="INSERT INTO img_tbl(`property_id`,`property_img`) VALUES (?,?)";
    if($stmt=$conn->prepare($query)){
        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$tmp_name){
            if(!copy($tmp_name,"uploads/{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}")){  // // not move_uploaded_file() ?
                echo "<div>copy error @ $tmp_name & uploads/{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}</div>";
            }
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST['property_id'],implode(' ',$_FILES['files']['name']))){
            echo "bind failed";  // $stmt->error;  // do not echo when public
        }elseif(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo "execute failed";  // $stmt->error;  // do not echo when public
        }else{
            header('location:listpro_img.php');
        }
        $stmt->close(); 
    }else{
        echo "prepare failed"; // $conn->error;  // do not echo when public
    }
    $conn->close();
}else{
    echo "insufficient data submitted";
}
```

I've written all of the superglobal checks into a single `isset()` call.  This syntax is valid, see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) if you are curious.

Your original process was using unsanitized data in your query which is not safe.  I have implemented a [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) with placeholders for you.  I don't know the expected data type of `$property_id` so I've assigned it as a string (`s`) but it might possibly be an integer (`i`) -- you will have to determine the right declaration there.

Make sure there is enough length in your `property_img` table column to receive the full length of your space-delimited image file names.  If there are many files uploaded and/or their names are relatively long, they might get truncated in a `VARCHAR(255)` field.

Edit: if `$propert_id` is to be an integer, you should limit the input field to numeric values only (a few ways to do this). Then in the form receiving code validate the submitted value to be safe.  As I mentioned earlier, replace `s` with `i` in the `bind` call.

Comment: am taking `property_id` as integer and `property_img` as varchar

Comment: I am using only $_POST and $_FILES . If am wrong please let me correct

Comment: @sudha I have run some actual tests and now I think I have the code mostly ironed out for you.  Please run this snippet and tell me if anything breaks.  I'll fix my answer if there are any errors in it.  Please remove your previous comments to tidy up the page.

Comment: with the help of your previous code ,I execute it and I got the result whatever I was looking for...Thank you for your help and valuable time.

Comment: I will be offline for a couple of hours.  Please prepare an online demo link with sample data and explain directories for me and ill help you when i return.

Comment: Thank you for reply ..I got the desired result